# Multiple dependent variables and ordinal regression?

Tags: spss, likert, ordered-logit

I am trying to analyse some ordinal Likert data against a few factors, such as job position, funding of last research and a yes / no question regarding ethics to see if these factors significantly affect the Likert results. My question is, as I can only put one dependent variable (outcome) into the test at a time, what do I do in the event I want to measure many dependent variables (I have about 12 Likert scale questions!). I am guessing I should not just do 12 tests due to false positives and messiness of writing up. Any help very appreciated, thanks.